# extracting image urls in an xml node and placing them in a new node

Tags: php, xml, regex, migration

I am migrating a bunch of content from an old blog, and I need it to be in XML format. The problem is, my old site doesn't contain a separate node for image urls, and the new one does, so I need to take an XML node that looks like this:

```
<entry_text>&lt;img src=&quot;http://site.com/image.jpg&quot; width=&quot;300&quot; height=&quot;429&quot; align=&quot;left&quot; hspace=&quot;5&quot; vspace=&quot;5&quot; /&gt;Lorem Ipsum Dolor sit amet
</entry_text>
```

and make it look like this:

```
<entry_text>Lorem Ipsum Dolor sit amet</entry_text>
<entry_image>&lt;img src=&quot;http://site.com/image.jpg&quot; width=&quot;300&quot; height=&quot;429&quot; align=&quot;left&quot; hspace=&quot;5&quot; vspace=&quot;5&quot; /&gt;</entry_image>
```

I found a php function for storing these variables in an array, but I'm not quite good enough with PHP to figure out how to create an XML node in the appropriate place from them:

```
$matches = array();
preg_match_all('!http://[^?#]+\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif)!Ui' , $string , $matches);
```

JQuery could work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex:

```
\<entry_text\>(?<url>.*?/&gt;)(?<text>.*?)\</entry_text\>
```

Replace:

```
<entry_text>${text}</entry_text><entry_image>${url}</entry_image>
```

Result:

```
<entry_text>Lorem Ipsum Dolor sit amet</entry_text><entry_image>&lt;img src=&quot;http://site.com/image.jpg&quot; width=&quot;300&quot; height=&quot;429&quot; align=&quot;left&quot; hspace=&quot;5&quot; vspace=&quot;5&quot; /&gt;</entry_image>
```

Comment: Tested with http://www.regular-expressions.info/download/csharpregexdemo.zip (still my favorite tool to quickly write &test regexes)

Comment: Thanks - I'm on mac so I can't use the tool - but I'll see if I can find something else. I don't suppose you know how to write this statement in javascript to apply the regex to a string. I'm getting an invalid RegEx error. This is what I tried: var entry_text = $('entry_text').text();
   
   var split = new RegExp('\<entry_text\>(?<url>.*?/&gt;)(?<text>.*?)\</entry_text\>');